# Modify testNG HTML report

Tags: html, selenium, report, testng

I am running some tests using testNG and Selenium. The test data comes from a CSV file. I have 17 parameters coming from this CSV file. Everything is working fine, but I want to change the testNG HTML report.

[image: screenshot showing testNG report]

I want to change the parameter # to something that I can easily recognize. So instead of Parameter #1, step number. And Parameter #2 = step description. And parameter #5 is click on element.

Is that possible, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doing this in testNg looks like this (EmailableReport class):

```
...
writer.print("<th>Parameter #");
writer.print(i);
writer.print("</th>");
...
```

So, I believe that answer would be:
You need to create custom report implementing testNG listeners (reportNg source code could be a good example) or build you own testNg version changing what you need. Not sure that the last is a good approach.